# iOS: Best practice for syncing large quantities of records.

Tags: ios, synchronization

I am syncing a phone with a website running on a server through JSON.  For small numbers of records, I can simply pull all the server records and if any are not present on handheld copy to handheld and viva versa.

However, pulling say 10,000 records from the server regularly to compare to those on the handheld is slow and inefficient.

Is there a known best practice to handle this.

One approach I have tried is to mark new records on server and then only pull the new ones and afterwards mark them pulled.  However, given the vagaries of network transfer, this is prone to mistakes from timeouts etc.  When you pull all the records, you know for sure what is and is not present but the process is unacceptably slow.

Wondering if this is a solved problem i.e. there is a best practice for syncing large number of records.

Thanks for any suggestions.